# Accessing value from dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar

```
export async function signIn({ dispatch }, data) {
  Loading.show()
  firebaseAuth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then(async res => {
      Loading.hide()
      // if (!res.user.emailVerified) {
      //   dispatch('setNotification', {
      //     ...failed,
      //     message: 'Email not verified!'
      //   })
      //   return
      // }
      res.user.getIdToken().then(token => {
        Loading.hide()
        const { uid } = res.user
        tempStorage.token = token
        tempStorage.localId = uid
        storage.delete(StorageKeys.token)
        storage.set(StorageKeys.token, token)
        storage.set(StorageKeys.localId, uid)
        dispatch('setNotification', {
          ...success,
          message: 'Successfully login!'
        })
        dispatch('getUserProfile')
```

// i need to access the value here from getUserProfile function

```
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Loading.hide()
      var msg = ''
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'auth/wrong-password':
          msg = 'Wrong password'
          break
        case 'auth/user-not-found':
          msg = 'User not found'
          break
        case 'auth/too-many-requests':
          msg = 'Account temporarily suspended'
      }

      dispatch('setNotification', {
        ...failed,
        message: msg
      })
    })
}


export async function getUserProfile({ dispatch, commit }) {
  try {
    const serviceUrl = `${urls.users}/${tempStorage.localId}`
    const { data } = await request.get(serviceUrl)
    commit('setUser', data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, 'err')
  }
}
```

How do i access the value from this disptach(getUserProfile) function???

```
 if (data.attributes.roles.includes('admin')) {
       this.$router.push({ path: routesConfig.name.training })
     } else {
       this.$router.push({ path: routesConfig.name.profile })
     }
```

i want this condition to run on basis of dispatch function
result and the upper condition will redirect me to different pages on basis of role

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can not copy and paste code from an image.... Paste in the code! Stackoverflow has the ability to show formatted code.

Comment: `How do i access the value from this...` What value?

Comment: I edited it. Could you please check and help